# Google Place Api- at multiple location

Tags: ios4, google-places-api

I am using Google Place api to show location in iphone. i am using ClLocation manager class to get current location of device which will passed as parameter of api.

but it doesn't work every time at different places in multiple devices.

any help ??

Answer (score 0):

check this out

> http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches

you can
its a normal web service, post a request and get an XML / JSON list

A Place Search request is an HTTP URL of the following for

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/output?parameters

e.g

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Gets the JSON output as

```
{
  "html_attributions" : [
    "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.yellowpages.com.au/\"\u003eYellow Pages\u003c/a\u003e"
  ],
  "results" : [
    {
      "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
          "lat" : -33.8719830,
          "lng" : 151.1990860
        }
      },
        "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
        "id" : "677679492a58049a7eae079e0890897eb953d79b",
        "name" : "Zaaffran Restaurant - BBQ and GRILL, Darling Harbour",
        "rating" : 3.90,
        "reference" : "CpQBjAAAAHDHuimUQATR6gfoWNmZlk5dKUKq_n46BpSzPQCjk1m9glTKkiAHH_Gs4xGttdOSj35WJJDAV90dAPnNnZK2OaxMgogdeHKQhIedh6UduFrW53wtwXigUfpAzsCgIzYNI0UQtCj38cr_DE56RH4Wi9d2bWbbIuRyDX6tx2Fmk2EQzO_lVJ-oq4ZY5uI6I75RnxIQJ6smWUVVIHup9Jvc517DKhoUidfNPyQZZIgGiXS_SwGQ1wg0gtc",
        "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
        "vicinity" : "Harbourside Centre 10 Darling Drive, Darling Harbour, Sydney"
    },
    {
      "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
          "lat" : -33.8722580,
          "lng" : 151.1986550
        }
      },
        "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
        "id" : "27ea39c8fed1c0437069066b8dccf958a2d06f19",
        "name" : "Criniti's Darling Harbour",
        "rating" : 3.60,
        "reference" : "CnRwAAAA-5kh5WZ3m1CMTO3LslvhRtAYsrOcQP7wB9AE1bV5R6Bd46NN5wB16MtImXWQ9eS1nWVbV_j-8iXYXRpU13Efp1t_d-Dp4WfEsFcYj-_g6db1SC1vAukyeCyotjS5xrwhzqWWAhgmA4qIliWeev2u1BIQprWzxl_hkj_w3QdTiUBYKxoUDVTjF4RugJdaJWkC4n6w6pSajKw",
        "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
        "vicinity" : "Shop 461, 2-10 Darling Drive, Harbourside Shopping Centre, DARLING HARBOUR"
    },
    ...additional results...
  ],
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

Get XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaceSearchResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <name>Zaaffran Restaurant - BBQ and GRILL, Darling Harbour</name>
  <vicinity>Harbourside Centre 10 Darling Drive, Darling Harbour, Sydney</vicinity>
  <type>restaurant</type>
  <type>food</type>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>-33.8719830</lat>
    <lng>151.1990860</lng>
   </location>
  </geometry>
  <rating>3.9</rating>
  <icon>http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png</icon>
  <reference>CpQBjAAAAJd_vFgeIo6ogU2gDLEe85XpxRi8LwIQXSVcPS5dxGIytvbNWic7gTlGIleeFRbrP-Rs4_V6AmCcF1RtaUXcb26_Oai6k6n34Ag17Cle3pnVl740CyNpp0VT48lOf7XkMngj75wKHqnApPZ9Bfcn0myuYeEZoKXw7c3pneO4Ty8FTxDqQyLiJk8CAkodTzSn5BIQj0ovOoMS5u-ds6_jygEGxRoUbKMNq2DBZdiS16jO3yku2DOBwNI</reference>
  <id>677679492a58049a7eae079e0890897eb953d79b</id>
 </result>
 <result>
  <name>Criniti's Darling Harbour</name>
  <vicinity>Shop 461, 2-10 Darling Drive, Harbourside Shopping Centre, DARLING HARBOUR</vicinity>
  <type>restaurant</type>
  <type>food</type>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>-33.8722580</lat>
    <lng>151.1986550</lng>
   </location>
  </geometry>
  <rating>3.6</rating>
  <icon>http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png</icon>
  <reference>CnRwAAAAwE_vlF04Iix2hijlKQsJLhpvAj8hwpfXGxtc0ckpBe0d54-rk4dxn8d1ZbaPGxxYfytkf4WJ7l5UC4Zh8jFZg0MTu1S8d66BK4vb2ktpAsKkfb28i3Mrf77ORRPXXjWwRtA7PEEfMP07mjfX3Xdg-RIQwjSMECQHM5S9WAohBIVB0BoUAb4i1DW-fL9E6XbgiDnmyZKrzRE</reference>
  <id>27ea39c8fed1c0437069066b8dccf958a2d06f19</id>
 </result>
 ...additional results...
 <html_attribution>Listings by &lt;a href="http://www.yellowpages.com.au/"&gt;Yellow Pages&lt;/a&gt;</html_attribution>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

Comment: Hii , Thanks for the response but i am using the same thing that is mentioned in the google place api as well as above but the problem is its not getting any data if location changes...even on some devices it works fine but in other it doesnt when we testing it at different locations.